# Registering Class to Ninject and injecting that class in Constructor

Tags: c#, ninject

I am using NHibernate, and I have a BootStrapper class that has a method that returns an ISession.  In my Repository class I am passing it an ISession Object.  In my Controller, I am passing its constructor an IRepository object.

I have been successful in binding my IRepository to Repository class, but I can't figure out how to bind/register my Repository class so that it receives a ISession object from the BootStrapper class when it is instantiated and bind my controller to recieve a IRepository object when it is created.

My Code:

```
    public interface IProductsRepository
{
    IQueryable<Product> Products { get; }
    void SaveProduct(Product product);
}


public class MySqlProductsRepository : IProductsRepository
{
    private readonly ISession _session;

    public MySqlProductsRepository(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    public IQueryable<Product> Products
    {
        get
        {
            return _session.CreateCriteria(typeof (Product)).List<Product>().AsQueryable();
        }
    }


public class BootStrapper
{

    public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();

    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        var cfg = new Configuration().Configure(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "nhibernate.config"));
        cfg.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionStringName, System.Environment.MachineName);
        NHibernateProfiler.Initialize();
        return cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static ISession GetSession()
    {
        return SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
    }
}


public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private readonly IProductsRepository _productsRepository;

    public AdminController(IProductsRepository productsRepository)
    {
        _productsRepository = productsRepository;
    }
}

public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel = new StandardKernel(new DaisyBlossomsServices());

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
            return null;
        return (IController) _kernel.Get(controllerType);
    }

    public class DaisyBlossomsServices : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IProductsRepository>().To<MySqlProductsRepository>();

        }
    }
}
```

How do I bind a ISession to MySqlProductsRepository so it receives an ISession object for its constructor, and how do I bind it so my controller receives an IProductsRepository in its constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can bind ISession to a Provider. In this case you can change the BootStrapper class to inherit from Provider and implement the CreateInstance method.

That would look like that:

```
public class BootStrapper : Provider<ISession>
    {
        .....
        protected override ISession CreateInstance(IContext context)
        {
            return GetSession();
        }
        ....
    }
```

After that just add the binding to your modul:

```
public class DaisyBlossomsServices : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IProductsRepository>().To<MySqlProductsRepository>();
            Bind<ISession>().ToProvider<BootStrapper>();
        }
    }
```

That should do it.